# Delete multiple rows from a table with a single query when the row ids are not consecutive

Tags: postgresql

I've created a mass delete feature on my website where the user gets to select which rows they want to delete before pressing a delete button. It currently works by creating an array containing each selected row's id, before looping through that array and calling a delete query for each one. I was wondering if there is a way to do with with a single query, while keeping in mind that the user may want to keep a row that in between the rows they would like to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN` clause for this.
Sample query may look like below

`DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 4, 6, 7)`